# Como configurar e verificar o MySQL para melhorar a perfomance

Tags: mysql

Como configurar o servidor MySQL para obter uma melhor performance em relação ao uso de memória, processamento e uso de cache onde a maquina possui recursos limitados? Existe alguma ferramenta que possa me auxiliar a definir as melhores configurações para meu servidor?

Estou tendo problemas com o tempo de resposta de consultas SQL devido ao alto número de dados no banco de dados, e o problema não está nas consultas ou modelagem, pois funcionava bem em outra maquina virtual com as mesmas configurações, porem ela foi corrompida e perdi as configurações.

- Total de 5Gb de dados;
- As tabelas são InnoDB;
- O servidor é virtualizado atualmente com 512Mb de memória RAM e 20Gb;
- Arquitetura 32bits;
- Sistema operacional Ubuntu Server 14;
- Versão do MySQL 5.5.46;
- As tabelas e índices estão otimizados;
- O Sistema é feito na linguagem PHP;
- Versão do PHP 5.5;
- Utiliza PDO.

O arquivo my.cnf

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name

# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: servidor com 512 mb de memória é complicado.. Sobre o volume de dados. 5GB não é considerado grande.. Numa configuração padrão, não afeta a performance. Talvez pode estar usando índices em demasia ou desnecessariamente ou montando queries muito complexas. Muitas vezes, uma simples troca de técnica numa query complexa ou uma mudança na modelagem, pode melhorar a performance consideravelmente.  Por isso é uma pergunta muito ampla. Há muitas variantes.

Comment: O problema não está nas consultas ou modelagem, pois funcionava bem em outra maquina virtual com as mesmas configurações. A maquina que estava antes foi corrompida e perdi as configurações.

Comment: adicione esse "pequeno detalhe" e outros relevantes na pergunta..

Comment: Adicionado mais detalhes à pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe um script em Perl chamado [MySQLTuner](http://mysqltuner.com/) que permite uma rápida e fácil visualização sobre o estado do MySQL Server. O script é recomendado para auxiliar na configuração para ter um ganho de performance.

Para obter o script:

```
wget http://mysqltuner.pl/ -O mysqltuner.pl
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/basic_passwords.txt -O basic_passwords.txt
```

Para executar:

```
perl mysqltuner.pl
```

No [site oficial](http://mysqltuner.com/) tem outras opções de utilização.

É necessário ter alguns modulos do Perl instaladas para executar, em minha tentativa foi necessário instalar `Text::Template`

```
sudo apt-get install libtext-template-perl
```

Ao executar irá pedir o usuário e senha caso não exista algum usuário sem senha.

```
Please enter your MySQL administrative login:
Please enter your MySQL administrative password:
```

Após digitar a senha irá gerar um relatório com as falhas e melhoria que poderá realizar para melhorar a performance e segurança.

No final terá as recomendações de melhorias.

```
-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: http://bit.ly/1mi7c4C
    Beware that open_files_limit (1024) variable 
    should be greater than table_open_cache ( 420)
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_limit (> 5M, or use smaller result sets)
    tmp_table_size (> 20M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 20M)
    table_open_cache (> 420)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 895M) if possible.
```

Comment: É possível rodar em servidor windows?